# C function from assembler code as a char string

Tags: c++, c, assembly, random

I was just wondering how random number is generated in assembler, I found question from russian stack overflow where a person asks rather not how to generate a random number in assembler, but how to implement that in c code using `_asm{}`.
[The answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/294885/379723) posted to his question surprised me (translated to eng):

```
char r[]="!!!!!!!!!!!№№№№№№№№№№№;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;55555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777";  // String, which length should be calculated

main()
{
    static unsigned long  (__cdecl *lenstr)(char*); // Pointer to function declaration. The method for passing parameters must be defined explicitly - it is different in different compilers

    static int i=0;
        if(!i)
            {
                static char s[]={
                    0x5a,
                    //pop %%edx
                    0x5f,
                    //pop %%edi
                    0xfc,
                    //cld
                    0x31,0xc9,
                    //xor %%ecx,%%ecx
                    0x31,0xc0,
                    //xor %%eax,%%eax
                    0x49,
                    //dec %%ecx
                    0xf2,0xae,
                    //repne scasв
                    0xf7,0xd1,
                    //not %%ecx
                    0x49,
                    //dec %%ecx
                    0x91,
                    //xchg %%eax,%%ecx
                    0x52,
                    //push %%edx
                    0xc3
                    //ret
                    }; // Array with assembler code
                lenstr=(unsigned long ( __cdecl *)(char*))&s; // Linking function pointer to to that array
                i=1;
            }               

            printf("%s%c%d%c%s\n","String length",' ',lenstr(r),' ',"symbols");
}
```

Two questions:

1. How long does the opportunity to put assembler code as a casted **`char`** array to function-pointer is existing and why it was developed?
2. I didn’t understand: calculating string length is kinda smart method of random number generation or it was just an example of machine code to pointer casting?

Comment: That won't work on most x86-64 OSes; non-const static data should be in a read+write page without exec permission.  You'd need additional tricks like VirtualProtect for Windows.  Also, that looks like a slow but small strlen, not a PRNG step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About the code example

Pasting the second answer's text from [your link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274449/random-assembler/294885#294885) to a translator gave me:

> And you can make it so that the machine code will be located in an array. Here's how you can write a program to count the number of characters in a string.

So it's only an example about how to use assembly code inside a C program. One could use `__asm`, but many don't like the syntax there. Therefore the assembly source code is first assembled externally (using NASM or FASM for example) and the resulting machine code is then embedded as a char array in the C program.

### Make the code executable

As Peter Cordes already mentioned, it's mostly not possible to execute code within data sections (where this char array is stored in the program). There are two ways to execute the code anyway: Either the appropriate compiler settings have to be set (to make the data section executable) or additional memory has to be allocated that is executable.

Under Linux, for example, you can use `mmap` to request such storage and then copy the code over:

```c
void* executableStorage = mmap(NULL, sizeof(executableCode),
                               PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                               MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);
memcpy(executableStorage, executableCode, sizeof(executableCode));
```

Under Windows, something similar can be done with `GlobalAlloc`, for example, which always returns an executable memory area.

### Random assembler

The first answer from the linked question is about the random numbers:

> The simplest option is to implement a linear congruent generator:
>
> ```
> R1 = (a * R0 + b) mod M
> ```
>
> Here `a` and `b` are constant coefficients (are selected), `M` is the modulus, the maximum value for a pseudo-random number (the minimum will be 0), `R0` is the result the previous call to the generator (for the first call, you can substitute any number).

[Linear-feedback shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) are another way to easily generate pseudo-random numbers.

### Why does this opportunity exists?

It is not really a functionality of C. Since C is very close to hardware, everything can be interpreted as data, pointer or even as program code. By casting with a certain data type, you can switch between them. Therefore this possibility will probably also be described somewhere. Conversely, C-code could also be interpreted as data:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Interpret the main function (program code) as data
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) main;

    // Print out some machine code of the main-function
    for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", data[i]);

        if ((i & 15) == 15)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So C offers these possibilities. Whether or not they are also allowed is not a matter for the language C. Security mechanisms, which are primarily provided by the operating system, can make memory areas and thus this data write-protected or non-executable.

Because of these security mechanisms, the way with the char array is no longer really practical. It was more of a quick-and-dirty solution, it's a bad programming style and impractical: every time the assembler code was changed, it would have to be manually transferred to the C program. Normally you would write the assembler code in a separate file and then link the assembled object file with the C object files:

```html
   assembly                 object              executable
 source code                 files                program
               assembler               linker
ASSEMBLY.asm ────────────> ASSEMBLY.o ───┬───>  ./PROGRAM
                                         │
              c-compiler                 │
   PROGRAM.c ────────────> PROGRAM.o  ───┘

c source code
```

Comment: That example would have worked on ancient 32-bit Windows without PAE page tables; before that there was no convenient way to mark a page readable but not executable.  So perhaps it was copy/pasted from something really old.  Also worth pointing out that you *can* just use `_asm{}` if that's what you want; it sucks for performance but it's not worse than hand-assembling into a char array, as long as you're making a 32-bit build (or using clang or ICC, not MSVC).

Comment: It's dated Feb 6, 2014.

Comment: And maybe the poster copy/pasted it from somewhere else, or dug it out of old notes, without checking its validity.  Or only tests inline asm in a 32-bit VM running Win2k or Win98?  No idea.  Or maybe it's just a bad answer if they posted a non-working example and don't mention how to actually make a `static char[]` array executable.  (I don't read Russian and didn't try autotranslate.)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. From Your answer I understood the only main idea - putting code in `char` array, situated in stack is extremely wrong because of most compilers non-support or stack overflow. So if I just make, for instance `char *code = new char[1024]` it is ok.

Comment: But I do not understand where this opportunity is documented? Why does it exists? It is more interesting for me.

Comment: I added another paragraph to my answer. Also: hackers know to store code in arrays or on the stack: during a code injection attack, they are written with code that is independent of the position. If a buffer overflow occurs, the return address on the stack is overwritten and the code is executed. See: [stack buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)

Comment: @Artur differentiating between different parts of memory (e.g. stack, heap and code) are just conventions to make things easier for programmers.  to the computer/CPU it's all just "memory" and hence the programmer is free to abuse conventions however they please.  these (ab)uses were historically easier because the cost/benefits of protection were less obvious, but now tools like non-execute and ASLR are common to protect against attackers

Comment: >main function machine code printing. Me: I have seen everything in c, no one can’t surprise me. @fcdt: hold my beer